# What are the differences between Inception Score and Fréchet Inception Distance?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks

From the articles I've read about image generation using GANs, the Inception Score measures two things simultaneously: the variety of images (diversity) and the distinct quality of each image. Does Fréchet Inception Distance also measures these things ? If so, what are the differences between them ? Could someone please explain ? Thanks